# Angular Detect application hit

Tags: angular

Interview Question: I have 3 applications A,B & C which are pointing to same server. I want to identify from which application hit is going to server.

Mý reply 'we can send some key in UI object' But interviewer was not happy with this answer. please help me with this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can identify based in URL OR based on IP Address.

**E.x:**

51.138.10.21/login

In server , you can get URL data and compare or check which app has request for any API.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any other way? as url or ip can change in future.

Comment: @Jay I'll update my answer if I got other answer. Can you please up vote my answer so other developers can also get advantage and also they can contribute.